# mysql string to date conversion

Tags: mysql

Need help to suggest sql query where I have a varchar column called Timing like below

```
+---------------------+
| Timing         | MO |
+---------------------+ 
|7/11/2016 20:45 |ABC |
|7/12/2016 20:45 |ABC |
|2016-07-11 00:00|ABC |
|2016-07-12 00:00|ABC |
+---------------------+
```

I need to extract date from the Timing column but tricky part is the date is not always in same format. I need to output timing column as below

```
+-------------+
| Timing  | MO|
+-------------+
|7/11/2016|ABC|
|7/12/2016|ABC|
|7/11/2016|ABC|
|7/12/2016|ABC|
+-------------+
```

Comment: Why you are adding date in `varchar` field and why in different formats?

Comment: The timing column is imported from multiple csv's. I dont have control over how timing is populated in those csv's

Comment: You can convert it in a same while importing... right or not?

Comment: yeah I can. But the number of csv's are numerous.  I automated to  loop through each csv using Load data infile command to import data into the mysql tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple enough using substring and replace functions to cast varchar as data and recast them to you required output. 
for example

```
DROP TABLE T;
CREATE TABLE T (TIMING VARCHAR(20),MO VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('7/11/2016 20:45' ,'AB'), 
('7/12/2016 20:45' ,'AB'),
('2016-07-11 00:00','AB'), 
('2016-07-12 00:00','AB'), 
('27/06/2016 20:45' ,'AB'), 
('29/05/2016 20:45' ,'AB')
*/

SELECT  *,
            CASE
                WHEN INSTR(TIMING,'/') = 0 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN INSTR(TIMING,'-') = 5 THEN  CAST(TIMING AS DATE)
                    end
                WHEN INSTR(TIMING,'/') = 3 THEN  
                    CAST(
                    CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),8,4)
                    ,'-'
                    ,SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),5,2)
                    ,'-'
                    ,SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),1,2)
                    )
                    AS DATE
                    )
                WHEN INSTR(TIMING,'/') = 2 THEN  
                    CAST(
                    CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),7,4)
                    ,'-'
                    ,SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),4,2)
                    ,'-'
                    ,SUBSTRING(CONCAT('0',TIMING),1,2)
                    )
                    AS DATE
                    )
            END 
FROM        T
```

results in

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 7/11/2016 20:45  | AB   | 2016-11-07                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 7/12/2016 20:45  | AB   | 2016-12-07                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 2016-07-11 00:00 | AB   | 2016-07-11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 2016-07-12 00:00 | AB   | 2016-07-12                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 27/06/2016 20:45 | AB   | 2016-06-02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| 29/05/2016 20:45 | AB   | 2016-05-02                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------
```

You do have to code for every known variant - in this case I have identified that 7/11/2016 needs to left padded with zero and slashes replaced with dashs before date conversion. Hopefully you have a limited number of date variations in your source to code for and you will end up with a large query - but that's life. God luck,

Comment: There are only two variations in the date formats "7/11/2016 20:45" & "2016-07-11 00:00" .  I think your solution is very close enough:). only thing is the the month in row 3rd and 4th i.e 2016-07-11, 2016-07-12 needs to be like this 2016-11-07 2016-12-07. can we do that as well. please. Thanks alot

Comment: I figured that out. Thanks a lot. saved my day